# Last Order Per Item with Price

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

I'm using Microsoft SQL and more specifically LinnWorks for order management.  I would like to extract the last order for each [SKU] and the [Price] paid for it.  I have gotten so far, but I think my approach is incorrect as I get a different row for each price paid.

This is the LinnWorks Table layout;

[image: LinnWorks Table layout]

And this is what I have tried, which works fine until the price is added;

```
SELECT
    si.ItemNumber AS [SKU],
    DATEDIFF("d",MAX(o.dReceievedDate), GETDATE()) AS [Last Ordered],
    oi.fpricePerUnit AS [Price],
    si.RetailPrice AS [MSRP]
FROM [Order] o
INNER JOIN OrderItem oi 
    on o.pkOrderID = oi.fkOrderID
LEFT OUTER JOIN StockItem si 
    on si.pkstockItemId = oi.fkStockItemID_processed
WHERE o.Source = 'EBAY'
GROUP BY si.ItemNumber, oi.fpricePerUnit, si.RetailPrice
```

I understand why it does it (grouping), but I don't know the way to solve the problem.

Comment: I fI have understood your question.. I guess you need to add having max([Last Ordered])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
    si.ItemNumber AS [SKU],
    DATEDIFF("d",o.dReceievedDate, GETDATE()) AS [Last Ordered],
    row_number() over (PARTITION BY si.ItemNumber, oi.fpricePerUnit, si.RetailPrice 
       ORDER BY o.dReceievedDate DESC) rn,
    oi.fpricePerUnit AS [Price],
    si.RetailPrice AS [MSRP]
FROM [Order] o
INNER JOIN OrderItem oi 
    on o.pkOrderID = oi.fkOrderID
LEFT OUTER JOIN StockItem si 
    on si.pkstockItemId = oi.fkStockItemID_processed
WHERE o.Source = 'EBAY'
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: It is still producing duplicate line items. The only differing columns is the price and Last Ordered. Any other ideas?  Interesting reading there, some new things for me to learn.

Comment: I removed 'oi.fpricePerUnit' from the 'PARTITION BY' section (Wild guess) and it 'SEEMS' to be right!  WOW Thanks..

Comment: using sql server 2012 in above query,can we avoid second select (SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1).Like using any window function.Is there any way .

Comment: @KumarHarsh no, there is currently no way of avoiding the subset solution for this type of question